# How do entity self-tracking with changes in VM and UI?

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

my context: Entity Framework 4.0 + WCF Ria Data Service + Silverlight 4.
Suppose I have entity People from EF, then I created PeopleVM like:

```
public class PeopleViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public PeopleViewModel(){
       //....
           this._hasChanges = MyDomainContext.HasChanges;
        }

        private People _People;
        public People People
        {
            get { return _People; }
            set
            {
                if (value != this._People)
                {
                    value = this._People;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("People");
                }
            }
        }

        private bool _hasChanges;
        public bool HasChanges
        {
            get { return this._hasChanges; }
            set
            {
                if (this._hasChanges != value)
                {
                    this._hasChanges = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("HasChanges");
                }
            }
        }

        //........

        private RelayCommand _saveCommand = null;
        public RelayCommand SaveCommand
        {
    //.....
        }

        private RelayCommand _cancelCommand = null;
        public RelayCommand CancelCommand
        {
    //.....
        }
   }
```

in UI xaml, I set binding as:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding People.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding People.LasttName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Then I set button in UI as:

```
<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"  IsEnabled="{Binding HasChanges}"/>
<Button Content="Undo" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding HasChanges}"/>
```

So what I want is:

1. initially, button should be disabled because there is no data changes.
2. when user type some in FirstName, LastName textbox, the button should be enabled.

But with above code, even I change firstname, lastname, the button still in disable status.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: are you sure when you instantiate `PeopleViewModel` the value of `MyDomainContext.HasChanges` is not null? try put break point there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your viewmodel's HasChanges property is not updated when your domain context HasChanges property is updated.  I typically just expose the Domain Context as a property on the view model and bind the buttons enabled state directly to its HasChanges property.

```
public class PeopleViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public PeopleViewModel(DomainContext context){
            this.Context = context;
        }

        public DomainContext Context
        { get; private set; }


        private People _People;
        public People People
        {
            get { return _People; }
            set
            {
                if (value != this._People)
                {
                    value = this._People;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("People");
                }
            }
        }

        //........

        private RelayCommand _saveCommand = null;
        public RelayCommand SaveCommand
        {
    //.....
        }

        private RelayCommand _cancelCommand = null;
        public RelayCommand CancelCommand
        {
    //.....
        }
   }
```

Here is the XAML for the UI to bind to the context's HasChanges:

```
<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"  IsEnabled="{Binding Context.HasChanges}"/>
<Button Content="Undo" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding Context.HasChanges}"/>
```

You must make sure that the People object is pulled out of the DomainContext in order for updates to affect the HasChanges property of that DomainContext.